# Firefox 48 on Ubuntu 16.04 crashing within seconds of being started

Tags: 16.04, firefox

Firefox 48 is crashing less than a minute after being started. Even without any user input it crashes. It is sending a crash reports of its own to Mozilla and Ubuntu does not get the crash.

Launching Firefox from the command line the output is the following:

```
$ firefox
ARTUR: - SHOW 
console.error: irc-client: 
  Message: Module `sdk/widget` is not found at resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/widget.js
  Stack:
    CuddlefishLoader/options<.load@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/loader/cuddlefish.js:79:18
@resource://jid0-k46ozsrmazz4545aueo0nxxk0c4-at-jetpack/irc-client/lib/main.js:10:16
CuddlefishLoader/options<.load@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/loader/cuddlefish.js:79:18
run@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/addon/runner.js:147:19
startup/</<@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/addon/runner.js:87:9
Handler.prototype.process@resource://gre/modules/Promise-backend.js:937:23
this.PromiseWalker.walkerLoop@resource://gre/modules/Promise-backend.js:816:7
this.PromiseWalker.scheduleWalkerLoop/<@resource://gre/modules/Promise-backend.js:750:11

console.error: irc-client: 
  Message: Module `sdk/widget` is not found at resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/widget.js
  Stack:
    CuddlefishLoader/options<.load@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/loader/cuddlefish.js:79:18
@resource://jid0-k46ozsrmazz4545aueo0nxxk0c4-at-jetpack/irc-client/lib/main.js:10:16
CuddlefishLoader/options<.load@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/loader/cuddlefish.js:79:18
run@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/addon/runner.js:147:19
startup/</<@resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/addon/runner.js:87:9
Handler.prototype.process@resource://gre/modules/Promise-backend.js:937:23
this.PromiseWalker.walkerLoop@resource://gre/modules/Promise-backend.js:816:7
this.PromiseWalker.scheduleWalkerLoop/<@resource://gre/modules/Promise-backend.js:750:11

ExceptionHandler::GenerateDump cloned child 6091
ExceptionHandler::SendContinueSignalToChild sent continue signal to child
ExceptionHandler::WaitForContinueSignal waiting for continue signal...
```

The details of the `firefox` package:

```
$ apt show firefox
Package: firefox
Version: 48.0+build2-0ubuntu0.16.04.1
Priority: optional
Section: web
Origin: Ubuntu
Maintainer: Ubuntu Mozilla Team <ubuntu-mozillateam@lists.ubuntu.com>
Bugs: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+filebug
Installed-Size: 112 MB
Provides: gnome-www-browser, iceweasel, www-browser
Depends: lsb-release, libasound2 (>= 1.0.16), libatk1.0-0 (>= 1.12.4), libc6 (>= 2.17), libcairo-gobject2 (>= 1.10.0), libcairo2 (>= 1.10.0), libdbus-1-3 (>= 1.9.14), libdbus-glib-1-2 (>= 0.78), libfontconfig1 (>= 2.11.94), libfreetype6 (>= 2.2.1), libgcc1 (>= 1:4.0), libgdk-pixbuf2.0-0 (>= 2.22.0), libglib2.0-0 (>= 2.31.8), libgtk-3-0 (>= 3.4), libgtk2.0-0 (>= 2.14), libpango-1.0-0 (>= 1.22.0), libpangocairo-1.0-0 (>= 1.14.0), libstartup-notification0 (>= 0.8), libstdc++6 (>= 5.2), libx11-6, libxcomposite1 (>= 1:0.3-1), libxdamage1 (>= 1:1.1), libxext6, libxfixes3, libxrender1, libxt6
Recommends: xul-ext-ubufox, libcanberra0, libdbusmenu-glib4, libdbusmenu-gtk4
Suggests: fonts-lyx
Replaces: kubuntu-firefox-installer
Task: ubuntu-desktop, ubuntu-usb, kubuntu-desktop, kubuntu-full, edubuntu-desktop, edubuntu-usb, xubuntu-desktop, lubuntu-desktop, ubuntustudio-desktop, ubuntu-gnome-desktop, ubuntukylin-desktop, ubuntu-mate-core, ubuntu-mate-desktop, ubuntu-mate-cloudtop
Xul-Appid: {ec8030f7-c20a-464f-9b0e-13a3a9e97384}
Supported: 5y
Download-Size: 46.2 MB
APT-Manual-Installed: yes
APT-Sources: http://ch.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
Description: Safe and easy web browser from Mozilla
 Firefox delivers safe, easy web browsing. A familiar user interface,
 enhanced security features including protection from online identity theft,
 and integrated search let you get the most out of the web.

N: There is 1 additional record. Please use the '-a' switch to see it
```

And the kernel:

```
$ uname -ra
Linux ENG-PAVIL-PC2 4.4.0-36-generic #55-Ubuntu SMP Thu Aug 11 18:01:55 UTC 2016 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

Any hint on how to solve this?

**Update I**: Running Firefox in safe mode changes nothing, it still crashes minutes after being started up. Using the `--debug` flag simply brings the gdb prompt up:

```
$ firefox --debug
GNU gdb (Ubuntu 7.11.1-0ubuntu1~16.04) 7.11.1
Copyright (C) 2016 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.  Type "show copying"
and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
<http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.
For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from /usr/lib/firefox/firefox...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
(gdb)
```

**Update II**: I have logged on with the guest user to try Firefox with that session. The constant crashing prevails there too.

Comment: Checking `man firefox` I see it has a couple options which may help you troubleshoot further. Can you try `firefox -safe-mode` and see if it is more stable? There is also `firefox --debug` to start it in a debugger.

Comment: have you tested it in another user's profile?

Answer (score 1):

> Message: Module `sdk/widget` is not found at resource://gre/modules/commonjs/sdk/widget.js

means you have a addon or a plugin that is NOT for this version of firefox. The line above it ...

```
console.error: irc-client:
```

points to the addon or plugin. There is a `require("sdk/widget");` or something similar in that software and the module "widget" does not exist.

[See this MDN article](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/widget): "widget" got removed in FF38 and [this is what it should be now](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Add-ons/SDK/High-Level_APIs/ui): `require("sdk/ui");`.

- possible fix: purge (so all addons get deleted too) ff 48 and install 49 from their system. Mine works like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

If you ever end up at a gdb prompt, type *run* and press Enter, then the program will run, at some point it will crash and then you can run *bt* to get a backtrace. That's the basics of debugging with gdb.